# In Google Sheets is there a way to get the sum of datas entered in the same cell everytime?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

E.g.: i have to track the calories i introduce in my body. Day after day i want to know how much calories remains for the rest of the week. Let's say the limit is 100 call/week
In a sheet i have cell A1 with the formula 100-"B1" so whenever i eat i fill B1 with the calories i got. Of course the second time i fill B1 the cell A1 reset to 100 and the subtraction start over.
But this is my goal: to have only one cell (B1) to fill everytime i eat and having A1 updated consequently. All in only one sheet.

I thought mybe with some script runned with a button i can achieve this. Like: i fill B1, run the script that subtract that value to A1, with no formulas in the cells.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is easy in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Add this script to Tools>>Script Editor and save it.

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range
  var col = range.getColumn()
  var row = range.getRow()
  if (col==2 && row==2) //check if edited cell is B2
  {var input = range.getValue();
   var current = activeSheet.getRange(2,4).getValue();
   activeSheet.getRange(2,4).setValue(current+input); //update current total calories
   range.clearContent();
  }
  //if not B2 do nothing
  else{
    return}
}
```

When you enter a value at B2, the current calories will be updated. You can simply reset the value of D2 every week and you can change the 100 in C2 to every value you want.

[image]
[image]
[image]